# SQL replace column by lookup on another table column

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can i copy from column A of tableA to column B on table A but applying a change on lookup table ? How can i do a query that does this ?

here's an example :

```
Table A
| colA|colB|
|'AAA'|NULL|
|'ABC'|NULL|
|'ADD'|NULL|

Table B
|colD |colE|
|'AAA'|'AA'|
|'ABC'|'AB'|
|'ADD'|'AD'|

Output:             or  Output:             
Table A                 Table A
|colA |colB|            |colA |colB|
|'AA' |NULL|            |'AAA'|'AA'|
|'AB' |NULL|            |'ABC'|'AB'|
|'AD' |NULL|            |'ADD'|'AD'|
```

EDIT:How can i pop back the query result into colB of original table?
I am using SQLite3

Comment: What SQL technology are you using?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple join:

```sql
SELECT a.colA, b.colE AS colB
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON b.colD = a.colA;
```

Comment: it works, thanks! how can I copy it then back to tableA?

Comment: It depends on your actual SQL databases (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.).  You should update your question and tell us this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the `colB` value in `a`, use a correlated subquery:

```
update a
    set colb = (select b.cole from b where b.cold = a.cola);
```